# Copying the macros and modules from one workbook to another and have all the VBA work in one master workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I need to know how to copy the VBA modules with the corresponding sheets with buttons and macros (that are assigned to the buttons) to an another workbook that also has VBA code in it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You should at least give it a go yourself. Stackoverlfow is not here so others can do all the work for you.

Comment: I tried for hours I'm in a rush.

Comment: I figured it out. If anyone ever needs any help I'm always there to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define you're variables (inputs) in the worksheet. You can define your variables to that worksheet or the whole entire workbook. It depends on what you are doing. Each variable must be unique and if you made a mistake just define it something else. This all relates to the VBA code so the names defined and arguments must match.

The variables are usually defined in the code where you are seeing an error. Define the variables in the worksheet by right clicking on the input and then you can call it by its name that is related to the code.